# What is the explanation for Melisandre (Red Woman) seeing her reflection as old and frail?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In episode one of season six there is a scene where the Red Woman (Melisandre) removes her clothes and looks at her reflection.

See in this clip,

My take on this scene was that she has done some really horrible things for the Lord of Light and she for the first time in the series feels conscious about what she has done. So when she looks in the mirror it shows her inner self which is ugly from all the terrible things she has done up until now. Of coarse that is just my thoughts and are probably wrong.

It obliviously is never explained in the show, but What is the message we are supposed to get from this? What does this mean? Why does she look old and frail?

Edit: For those in the comments who think the necklace is the source of her younger looks, she has taken a bath before and not had it on, so it can't be the necklace that makes her look young.

[image]

Comment: I took it to mean she had used magic to appear younger, but the mirror showed her **actual age**. Now I think about it though, I seem to recall her saying she was surprised that bringing a character back from the dead actually worked, suggesting that the power of the 'God of Light' had been increasing in **recent times** (dragons, anyone?). So 'her true self' seems more plausible. Though why that was 'aged' rather than with 'fangs & tentacles' is anyone's guess.

Comment: It seemed to me rather obvious that when she took off necklace illusion stopped to work and we could see how she really looks.

Comment: I'd assume that the downvotes are due to this question being nonsense. As is clearly shown, Melisandre herself is ancient and the magic necklace is helping to hide that. So it isn't just the reflection. You literally see her get in bed as an old woman; whatever makes you think only the reflection is showing her as old?

Comment: It also makes looks her suspiciously like a White Walker....

Comment: @BCdotWEB, And you have unequivocal evidence that the necklace is keeping her looking young? You see, it is people like you who claim a question is bad or not thought out, but you yourself are wrong. So you still agree the question is nonsense, I edited the question for you.

Comment: Your question is still wrong. "So when she looks in the mirror it shows her inner self" -- no, it shows her as she is without the glamour. **As we the viewers can see** when she shuffles to the bed etc. With regard to the "but she didn't wear the necklace in the bathtub and still looked young" argument: 99% sure that this is simply a mistake by the makers of GoT. Also, this question shouldn't even be tagged as ASOIAF since none of the above is book-related.

Comment: @BCdotWEB but much like the star-wars-legends tag, it also used to when the user is willing to accept answers from the books.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Also, if this is continuity error, maybe there is a quote from a show runner or GRRM that can back it up....

Comment: @BCdotWEB, You said, `I'd assume that the downvotes are due to this question being nonsense. As is clearly shown, Melisandre herself is ancient and the magic necklace is helping to hide that.` . But we have to assume it is not an error, don't we. And if we do, the question has plenty of validity. It is you who is making the assumptions, I am going off the evidence provided in the show.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I removed the book tag as you suggested. Please don't call people's questions "nonsense" - there are politer and more constructive ways to frame a criticism.

Comment: "I am going off the evidence provided in the show." Then why don't you admit the premise of your question is incorrect? It isn't just her reflection that is shown as old. Oh, and also: ["The Huffington Post spoke with actress Carice van Houten, who plays the Red Woman on the show, to confirm that when Melisandre takes off the necklace, her glamour is gone, revealing her true age. So, is it the truth? “Well, yes,” she replied."](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/carice-van-houten-melisandre-necklace_us_572a32b5e4b016f3789461fd)

Comment: @BCdotWEB, The first time we see her as old is in the reflection. I took that a face value and after that was just us being shown her projection of herself, so my premise is, "Why was she seeing herself that way". And I believe that is exactly what I asked in the question. You are aware I am asking b/c I don't know? I don't presume to know the answer then ask a question. And I was not aware they had the Huffinton post in Westoros? Again, I am drawing on nothing **BUT** what is in the show.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not that she **looks** old, but that she really **is** old.

Here are two lines from [an article](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/04/game-of-thrones-melisandre-how-old-season6-episode-1-red-woman) on her age:

> In an interview after Sunday’s season 6 premiere, show-runner David Benioff calls her “Several centuries old.”
>   ...
>
> Similarly, the actor who played Maester Cressen, Oliver Ford Davies, told journalists in 2013 that, according to van Houten, Melisandre is “400 years old.”

Edit to add: Other than the Children of the Forest and the Night's King, she might be the oldest character on Game of Thrones.

Answer (score 8):

This clip has David Benioff and D. B. Weiss explanation for this.

**In short, George RR Martin had indicated to them that Melisandre (Red Woman) was old and they took this opportunity to show that to the audience.**

Quoting the discussion from the video.

> **David Benioff:** There have been few hints before that Melisandre is much older than she appear going back to very early conversation with George  Martin about her, she is supposed to be several centuries old , so we always wanted to
>   show her true age and we were waiting for the right moment and this was it for us.
>
> **D. B. Weiss:** Her confronting the reality of her situation. Her appearance is a lie, just as the Lord of light's supposed promises to her and 
>   messages to her were lies. But at the end of episode one she is in the place where she really needs to look her real self in the eye
>   and come to terms with where she stands now
>
> **David Benioff:** And we see the real Melisandre, which is quite feeble and aged and yet you can see her in there.

Comment: Great answer. I would recommend transcribing the relevant quote in case the link ever goes dead.

Comment: Updated, its hard work typing text!